# Website nav not scrolling to correct div on phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, smartphone

When I click on the nav link it scrolls me to the top of the page on mobile instead of the correct id section. I am not sure why this is happening.

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function (event) {
        var id = $(this).attr("href");
        var offset = 110;
        var target = $(id).offset().top - offset;

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target
        }, 500);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

<div id="nav-ph">
    <div class="nav-btn-ph"></div>
    <ul class="main-nav-ph">
        <li><a href="#the-advantage">THE ADVANTAGE</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#services">OUR SERVICES</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#team">OUR TEAM</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#news">MAKING NEWS</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="the-advantage">
    <p>Advantage</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="services">
    <p>Services</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="team">
    <p>Team</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="news">
    <p>News</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="contact">
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Her is a link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BrentRansom/BEMr9/1/

Help needed!

Comment: add px to your target

Comment: I just tried the jsFiddle and it worked fine on my iPhone.  Of course it just jumped and didn't animate because you didn't enable jQuery.  But once I did enable jQuery ( http://jsfiddle.net/BEMr9/2/ ), the smooth scrolling worked just fine as well.

Comment: If i needed to create two different scroll events one for desktop and one for mobile how would I call the jquery and again and name it so they do not conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution I had to change the a tag id to a different name. I had matching id's.